# Protop and lrgExtent alerts

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db, protop

Presumably, every start of the protop agent, there are massive fixed-extent alerts, although in fact a new next variable extent has already been created. Is this normal behavior? In my opinion, these are false positives.

Examples:

site.resource   lrgExtent 807.2 > 500
site.resource   lrgExtent 807.2 > 700
site.resource   lrgExtent 807.2 > 800

Comment: [Can you please add some code so that the example can be preproduced](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `for each dictdb._FileList no-lock:
    if _FileList-OpenMode = "UNBUF" then next.
assign
     tt_configuration.lrgExtent  = max( _FileList-Size, tt_configuration.lrgExtent )
     tt_configuration.numExtents = tt_configuration.numExtents + 1
    .`

Answer (score 0):

If you have large extents then, yes, ProTop is going to alert on those at startup. The “large extent” alert is not related to such an extent being the last one nor does it matter that you have added a variable extent to your structure. The point is that it is large and therefore a potential problem.

(Possible problems include things like being more painful to manipulate if you ever have to dbrpr the database or perform “extent surgery” on a damaged db.)

The alert that you are asking about only says that there is at least one large extent. It doesn’t fire for every such extent so “massive alerts” don’t happen. Just one.

If you still don’t want the alert you can comment it out in alert.cfg.  (You could also increase the threshold to avoid the alert.) To avoid losing your changes to alert.cfg on updates create a localized version by adding your customer id to the name.  I.e. "alert.xyzzy.cfg" (your customer id is in etc/custid.cfg).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Tom. Are you planning to add alerts only for the latest extents?

Comment: There is a distinct alert for the last fixed size extent: pctLastX. By default it is disabled because most people are not managing their extent sizes. If you want to enable it add PCTLASTX=yes to bin/localenv.  (Stackoverflow really isn't intended for extended conversations - you might want to reach out to me via email.)